# Is it possible to change the colour of my Outlook desktop e-mail alert?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I am using Outlook 2010 and want to know if it is possible to change the colour of the desktop alert that materialises whenever a new message(s) arrive from the bland default colour to something more eye-catching.  Can this be done?  If so, how does one go about it?  Would it take modification of the registry in order to achieve this?

(For those of you who wish to attempt modifying the registry, I must stress that unless you are absolutely certain of what you are doing, you should **never** modify any registry keys as the repercussions could be devastating to your system.  I am a qualified Computer Scientist with specialisms in Artificial Intelligence, Networking, Machine Learning and Automated Algorithmic Decision-Making Processes, and I possess the necessary skills and knowledge required to successfully and safely modify said registry keys.)

Many thanks.

Comment: I don't see how your second paragraph has anything to do with the question... It's just advice to other people about the registry in general... You may be better off removing it, and just focus on the question :)

Comment: It serves as a warning for those who, when reading possible solutions, see some terminology that they recognise and think that they can resolve all their problems by performing these tasks - I don't want to indirectly cause anybody to have any problems that they can't handle.

Comment: SnookerFan, I [asked a question on Meta which you may find useful](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161972/liability-with-advice) ... However, I have no qualifications (other than a driving license, the only exam I ever passed!!) and would happily edit the registry on other peoples computer  :)

Comment: Also, this sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want this behaviour with the notification? Maybe there is a macro or third party extension which does what you want without needing to use the notification at all?

Comment: I want this feature simply because I would like the notification to be bright red for the simple reason that nothing else my screen is never bright red, and it will thus catch my eye better so that I don't miss any urgent e-mails.

Answer (score 0):

No, not in Outlook alone but, you can change the transparency which may help (or not)

1. Open Outlook.
2. Go to the top of the Ribbon and click the Office Button.
3. Click Options.
4. In the left pane, select Mail.
5. Go to the Message arrival section and click the Desktop Alert Settings button.
6. Click the Preview button.
7. Click and drag the generated Desktop Alert to the desired location on your desktop.
8. Click OK to close the Desktop Alert Settings window.
9. Click OK to close the Outlook Options window.

[Source](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/5165/outlook-2010-change-the-screen-location-that-the-desktop-alert-appears/)

The only other way, which gives minimal changes, is in Outlook, under, File - Options, General

In here, you change the colour scheme... However, this will effect more than just the Notification box!

Comment: Thank you, but this is not quite what I am after (the first thing I do when installing a new version of Outlook is to change the transparency to 0% (solid)!)